# How to orchestrate your own module in python

Tags: python, module, package, dependencies, python-import

The following picture shows a small orchestration for learning how to set up the orchestration when building a module in python
[image]

The module1 contains two functions and one depends on the other

outside of the module1 folder there is a main.py file that should import all the functions of the files up.py e double.py

as it can be seen in the screenshot the importing does not work in main.py
This are errors I get when importing:

```
from module1 import double
double.doublefunc('erer')
```

ERROR:
AttributeError: module 'module1.double' has no attribute 'doublefunc'

What would be the difference between an empty **init**.py and importing inside **init**.py? I had understood that **init**.py is normally empty, but it looks like there is not always the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

includes are relative.

so in the library files you have to refer to local files in the same folder. In your case in double.py you have to refer to up.py by `from .up import upfunc as mm` just like you do in the **init**.py

in the main.ipynb you have to import the python objects, not the files. so `from module1 import doublefunc as dd`, etc...